# writing posixAccount to LDAP doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ldap

I tried to write PosixAccount on LDAP to an existing user. i get no error, but when checking LDAP the new entry has not been written.

i added a new user first which is working well! 
=>

```
        public bool RegisterUser(UserObject userObj, HttpContext httpContext){
        bool success = false;

        //create a directory entry
        using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry())
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeCommonDataForDirectoryEntry(
                    de,
                    String.Format("{0}/{1}",
                        GetConfigEntry(Common.CommonDefinitions.CE_LDAP_CONFIG_SERVER, httpContext),
                        GetConfigEntry(Common.CommonDefinitions.CE_LDAP_CONFIG_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_ROOT, httpContext)),
                        httpContext);

                DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
                ds.SearchScope = System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree;
                ds.Filter = "(&(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(ou=people))";

                SearchResult result = ds.FindOne();
                if (result != null)
                {
                    DirectoryEntry myDirectoryEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
                    DirectoryEntry newEntry = myDirectoryEntry.Children.Add(String.Format("cn={0}", userObj.userName), "inetOrgPerson");

                    if (userObj.company != null && !userObj.company.Equals(String.Empty))
                        newEntry.Properties["businessCategory"].Add(String.Format("{0}", userObj.company));
                    newEntry.Properties["givenName"].Add(String.Format("{0}", userObj.firstName));
                    newEntry.Properties["sn"].Add(String.Format("{0}", userObj.lastName));
                    newEntry.Properties["uid"].Add(String.Format("{0}", userObj.userName));
                    newEntry.Properties["mail"].Add(String.Format("{0}", userObj.email));
                    userObj.password = GenerateSaltedSHA1(userObj.password);
                    newEntry.Properties["userPassword"].Add(String.Format("{0}", userObj.password));
                    newEntry.Properties["pager"].Add(String.Format("{0}", userObj.newsletter));
                    newEntry.Properties["initials"].Add(String.Format("{0}", GetConfigEntry(Common.CommonDefinitions.CE_MOWEE_PACKAGE_1, httpContext)));

                    newEntry.CommitChanges();
                    newEntry.RefreshCache();
                    success = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.Write("Exception : RegisterUser: " + ex);
                GeneralUtils.SendBugMail(ex, httpContext);
            }
        }
        return success;
    }
```

after that i want to write posixAccount for that user, which is not working
maybe someone can help me PLEASE and check what i did wrong !?

=>

```
     public bool WritePosixAccountDataForRegisteredUser(UserObject userObj, HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        bool success = false;

        //create a directory entry
        using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry())
        {
            try
            {
                InitializeCommonDataForDirectoryEntry(
                    de,
                    String.Format("{0}/ou=people,{1}",
                        GetConfigEntry(Common.CommonDefinitions.CE_LDAP_CONFIG_SERVER, httpContext),
                        GetConfigEntry(Common.CommonDefinitions.CE_LDAP_CONFIG_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_ROOT, httpContext)),
                        httpContext);

                DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher(de);
                ds.SearchScope = System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree;
                ds.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectClass=*)(cn={0}))", userObj.userName);

                SearchResult result = ds.FindOne();
                if (result != null)
                {
                    DirectoryEntry userEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

                    //mandatory attributes
                    /*
                     *      cn
                            gidNumber
                            homeDirectory
                            uid
                            uidNumber
                     * */

                    IADsPropertyList propList = (IADsPropertyList)userEntry.NativeObject;

                    ActiveDs.PropertyEntry myNewEntry1 = new ActiveDs.PropertyEntry();
                    ActiveDs.IADsPropertyValue propVal1 = new ActiveDs.PropertyValue();
                    propVal1.CaseIgnoreString = "posixAccount";
                    propVal1.ADsType = (int)ADSTYPEENUM.ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING;
                    myNewEntry1.Name = "objectClass";
                    myNewEntry1.Values = new object[] { propVal1 };
                    myNewEntry1.ControlCode = (int)ADS_PROPERTY_OPERATION_ENUM.ADS_PROPERTY_APPEND;
                    myNewEntry1.ADsType = (int)ADSTYPEENUM.ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING;
                    propList.PutPropertyItem(myNewEntry1);

                    ActiveDs.PropertyEntry myNewEntry2 = new ActiveDs.PropertyEntry();
                    ActiveDs.IADsPropertyValue propVal2 = new ActiveDs.PropertyValue();
                    propVal2.CaseIgnoreString = "504";
                    propVal2.ADsType = (int)ADSTYPEENUM.ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING;
                    myNewEntry2.Name = "gidNumber";
                    myNewEntry2.Values = new object[] { propVal2 };
                    myNewEntry2.ControlCode = (int)ADS_PROPERTY_OPERATION_ENUM.ADS_PROPERTY_APPEND;
                    myNewEntry2.ADsType = (int)ADSTYPEENUM.ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING;
                    propList.PutPropertyItem(myNewEntry2);

                    ActiveDs.PropertyEntry myNewEntry3 = new ActiveDs.PropertyEntry();
                    ActiveDs.IADsPropertyValue propVal3 = new ActiveDs.PropertyValue();
                    propVal3.CaseIgnoreString = "/data/WowzaMediaServer-3.0.3/content/mowee/" + userObj.userName;
                    propVal3.ADsType = (int)ADSTYPEENUM.ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING;
                    myNewEntry3.Name = "homeDirectory";
                    myNewEntry3.Values = new object[] { propVal3 };
                    myNewEntry3.ControlCode = (int)ADS_PROPERTY_OPERATION_ENUM.ADS_PROPERTY_APPEND;
                    myNewEntry3.ADsType = (int)ADSTYPEENUM.ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING;
                    propList.PutPropertyItem(myNewEntry3);

                    ActiveDs.PropertyEntry myNewEntry4 = new ActiveDs.PropertyEntry();
                    ActiveDs.IADsPropertyValue propVal4 = new ActiveDs.PropertyValue();
                    propVal4.CaseIgnoreString = "1100";
                    propVal4.ADsType = (int)ADSTYPEENUM.ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING;
                    myNewEntry4.Name = "uidNumber";
                    myNewEntry4.Values = new object[] { propVal4 };
                    myNewEntry4.ControlCode = (int)ADS_PROPERTY_OPERATION_ENUM.ADS_PROPERTY_APPEND;
                    myNewEntry4.ADsType = (int)ADSTYPEENUM.ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING;
                    propList.PutPropertyItem(myNewEntry4);

                    ActiveDs.PropertyEntry myNewEntry5 = new ActiveDs.PropertyEntry();
                    ActiveDs.IADsPropertyValue propVal5 = new ActiveDs.PropertyValue();
                    propVal5.CaseIgnoreString = userObj.userName;
                    propVal5.ADsType = (int)ADSTYPEENUM.ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING;
                    myNewEntry5.Name = "cn";
                    myNewEntry5.Values = new object[] { propVal5 };
                    myNewEntry5.ControlCode = (int)ADS_PROPERTY_OPERATION_ENUM.ADS_PROPERTY_APPEND;
                    myNewEntry5.ADsType = (int)ADSTYPEENUM.ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING;
                    propList.PutPropertyItem(myNewEntry5);

                    ActiveDs.PropertyEntry myNewEntry6 = new ActiveDs.PropertyEntry();
                    ActiveDs.IADsPropertyValue propVal6 = new ActiveDs.PropertyValue();
                    propVal6.CaseIgnoreString = userObj.userName;
                    propVal6.ADsType = (int)ADSTYPEENUM.ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING;
                    myNewEntry6.Name = "uid";
                    myNewEntry6.Values = new object[] { propVal6 };
                    myNewEntry6.ControlCode = (int)ADS_PROPERTY_OPERATION_ENUM.ADS_PROPERTY_APPEND;
                    myNewEntry6.ADsType = (int)ADSTYPEENUM.ADSTYPE_CASE_IGNORE_STRING;
                    propList.PutPropertyItem(myNewEntry6);

                    de.RefreshCache(new String[] { "objectClass" });
                    de.RefreshCache(new String[] { "gidNumber" });
                    de.RefreshCache(new String[] { "homeDirectory" });
                    de.RefreshCache(new String[] { "uidNumber" });
                    de.RefreshCache(new String[] { "cn" });
                    de.RefreshCache(new String[] { "uid" });

                    de.CommitChanges();
                    success = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Trace.Write("Exception : RegisterUser: " + ex);
                GeneralUtils.SendBugMail(ex, httpContext);
            }
        }
        return success;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error you get would be informative for diagnosing any further.

When you create an object in AD I am pretty sure even if you do not specify a CN you get a default naming attribute of CN set.  So this posixAccount create, which is setting cn, might be conflicting with an existing cn value.  I forget if CN is multivalued or single valued in AD, but if it is single valued this would make more sense.

Comment: I think the error you get would be informative for diagnosing any further.

the call following call succeeds =>

    de.CommitChanges();

i don't get any error, that is confusing me.

hmmm what you exactly mean is wrong with cn ? (should be the existing user which i wrote before, or not?)

Comment: @user2169239 When you create the object in AD, go look at it via an LDAP browser.  does it have a CN attribute already?  My guess is that it does.  Now you try to add posixAccount which requires CN so you go to add it again.  If AD's CN is single valued, then that is an illegal operation adding a second CN attribute value.  That is where I am going with this.

Comment: yes there is already a cn attribute. and single valued is set to "no".